# Need help to only print one small part

Tags: slicing, stl

I'm in dire need to reprint a small chunk of a print that got messed up during print because the support for it broke which I cannot explain whatsoever.

Anyway. I need to edit the STL file and I don't know what tool to use since Blender is definitely not user friendly for just a simple cut and past.

Anyone got an idea on what I should try to do? Reprinting is definitely out of question since that would take at least another 20 hours, that I haven't got, to reprint the whole thing and I would also just waste a lot of PLA.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so I asked in my facebook group and a friendly fellow game me the tip to use Meshmixer from AutoCAD and then check a video on Plane cut. I only needed 3 simple cuts and the piece I needed was all ready to print. :) 40 Minutes to print and only 3g of PLA to spend :)

Answer (score 1):

You could import the STL file in a 3D CAD modelling program and edit it there.

To not give an opinionated answer, there are many free or paid alternatives available. Loading the STL generally requires it to be scaled down to one tenth of the imported size and transform the surface model into a solid. Once you have the solid you can cut away what you do not need.

Comment: As I mentioned in the first question I didn't manage to use blender and couldn't immediatly find what I needed. ^^
But yeah meshmixer did it for me and I was more or less happy with the result :)

Answer (score 1):

Most slicers like Cura allow doing a Z-Plane cut by pushing the model "into" the base or setting a negative Z position. This is usually very helpful if a print fails on a known layer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use FlashForge in the future(I know that you already solved the problem, but still), the slicer program that I use as well. Blender is not very good for tasks like slicing, as it is rather for creating the actual models you would like to print. Programs like FlashForge provide you with a kind of preview of the model, which is better for slicing as you can see the expected result. 
Another good thing about FlashForge is that you can push models you created with Blender down in the Z-axis and then slice it off at Z=0 , so you can just use your old model without having to change/modify anything about it.

However, as you didn't specify on what printer you are using, I couldn't make sure if FlashForge is compatible with your device. Please send me a comment so that I can come back to this later on, if it is not compatible, there will still probably be a comparable program to FlashForge.

Please also keep in mind that in order to fit the two prints together to get the model you would like in the first place, you need PLA glue or something like that for assembling the two pieces, as well as a roughened surface to apply it to.

I hope this helps you in the future, Kind regards, Max

Comment: sorry for the late followup. I have an Ender 3.